# Java, Regex: Replace fields in Json by field key

Tags: java, regex

Requirements:

For each Json field where key matches specified constant replace value with another constant.

```
{"regular":"a", "sensitive":"b"}
```

Parameters "sensitive", "*****".
Expected:

```
{"regular":"a", "sensitive":"*****"}
```

Values may, or may not have double quotes around them. Replacement constant is double quouted always. Json may be malformed. Java implementation preferably.

Key comparison is case insensitive.

Comment: Not a good idea to manipulate JSON using regex. Use some JSON library

Comment: @TheLostMind I have a requirement that Json may be malformed.

Comment: hmm. Well, in that case, there are ways to achieve this. Even though I've added an answer to this, I strongly recommend *avoiding it*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *positive lookbehind* to achieve this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "{\"regular\":\"a\", \"sensitive\":\"b\"}";
    String key = "sensitive";
    String val = "****";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=\"" + key + "\":\")(\\w+)", val));
     key = "regular";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=\"" + key + "\":\")(\\w+)", val));

}
```

O/P :

```
{"regular":"a", "sensitive":"****"}
{"regular":"****", "sensitive":"b"}
```

Comment: how can I make key comparison case-insenstive?

Comment: used (?i) for case insensitive matching

Comment: what would you do if "sensitive" were an object?  {sensitive:{x:y} and you wanted to wipe the object and put in the string?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how malformed your "JSON" is, the following might work - if not, we need more test cases:

```
"sensitive"\s*:\s*  # match "sensitive":
(                   # capture in group 1:
 "[^"]*"            # any quoted value
|                   # or
 [^\s,{}"]*         # any unquoted value, ending at a comma, brace or whitespace
)                   # end of group 1
```

In Java:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(
    "(?x)\"sensitive\"\\s*:\\s* # match \"sensitive\":\n" +
    "(                          # capture in group 1:\n" +
    " \"[^\"]*\"                # any quoted value\n" +
    "|                          # or\n" +
    " [^\\s,{}\"]*              # an unquoted value, ending at comma, brace or whitespace\n" +
    ")                          # end of group 1",
    "\"sensitive\":\"******\"");
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VGQCBV/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
String t= "{\"regular\":\"a\", \"sensitive\":\"b\"}"; //{"regular":"a", "sensitive":"b"}
String r = t.replaceAll("(\\s*)\"?sensitive\"?\\s*:\\s*\"?b\"?\\s*", "$1\"sensitive\":\"*****\""); 
System.out.println("output "+r); //output {"regular":"a", "sensitive":"*****"}

t= "{\"regular\":\"a\",sensitive:b}"; //{"regular":"a", "sensitive":"b"}
r = t.replaceAll("(\\s*)\"?sensitive\"?\\s*:\\s*\"?b\"?\\s*", "$1\"sensitive\":\"*****\""); 
System.out.println("output "+r); //output {"regular":"a","sensitive":"*****"}
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/uHUhEl/1/